# Error at my microcode

Tags: microcode

I have this error at ubuntu 18.10. I already tried ubuntu 16 and fedora 28.

```
stephany@pop-os:~$ dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.039771] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540433077 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.039776] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540433077 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.039779] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540433077 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.039782] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540433077 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    1.153987] microcode: sig=0x906e9, pf=0x20, revision=0x8e
[    1.154215] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Updated

```
stephany@pop-os:~$ dmesg | grep mce
[    0.024000] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
[    0.040355] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.040356] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee2000000040110a
[    0.040357] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ffc0 MISC 7880010086 
[    0.040360] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540479088 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.040360] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.040361] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ee2000000040110a
[    0.040362] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce40 MISC 47880010086 
[    0.040364] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540479088 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.040365] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 8: ee2000000040110a
[    0.040366] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ff40 MISC 7880010086 
[    0.040368] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540479088 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
[    0.040369] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 9: ee2000000040110a
[    0.040369] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ff00 MISC 3880010086 
[    0.040371] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906e9 TIME 1540479088 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8e
```

Comment: The processor code suggests that it is a i7-7700K. Machine Code Exceptions (MCE) can be hard to isolate. As a test try [kernel 4.19](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/). microcode 8E is the most recent.

Comment: Did you tried to update your BIOS? Same issue at somewhere suggested that it is gone after BIOS upgrade. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1455232

Comment: Yes the microcode is already the latest version so I don't think it's microcode related.

Comment: I updated the kernel to 4.19 and I have the same error

Comment: Do you have any other problems with the machine, or just the MCE's? Did Ubuntu 16 error the same way? What kind of computer? Edit your question to include `sudo lshw -c memory`. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for at least one complete pass. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 1):

They are not necessarily microcode error.

The "microcode" string in mce logs are just telling you which CPU is having errors and which microcode version it has.

You should inspect dmesg lines around those mce logs first.

Comment: How I do this? Sorry I'm new as user linux

Comment: try grep mce instead of microcode this time

Comment: I updated my question